# Executing a Powershell script of IIS Service Add-New-WebSite from php Error

Tags: php, powershell, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute a power-shell script Of IIS Service from PHP, but it throws an error.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- php code -->
<?PHP
  $pssf = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sam\sam.ps1";
  $op = Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File '.$pssf);
  echo $op;
?>

<!-- Powershell script code -->
try{
  Import-Module WebAdministration
  ## Creating a simple website using the cmdlets
  New-Website -Name "sa" -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ -Port 82;
  Write-Host ("`nEntered successfull.`n`n");
}
catch {
  Write-Host "An error occurred:"
  Write-Host $_
}
```

Here I have mentioned above is the code of PHP and PowerShell script where I have used to do my task. While I use this code to execute the code but I am facing the issue. Here I have mentioned the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: i have mentioned in the output screenshoot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwkak.png